# How to create certain pixels translucent in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, lighting, shading

I'm currently making a game in pygame, for this game I plan on making a title screen with a lamp that flickers and so i would like to create a pseudo shadow/light radius to create the look of flickering lights in a dark area. I know that you can use .set_colorkey to make images transparent but is there a way to make pixels and specific colours translucent so that you can see through it but can still have the color? If not, what would the best trick be to make it work like that?

I am using pygame but any modules or things that can help are greatly appreciated.

So far I have tried to complete it with pixel art and also with the set_colorkey but cant think or find any other solutions.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at pygame.Color (https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html), it supports rgba, setting the 'a' (alpha) value will change the transparency of a pixel.